# Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

Pycharm 5

> Problem : Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=350m'

Java version

> java version "1.9.0-ea" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.9.0-ea-b91) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.9.0-ea-b91, mixed mode)

I have commented the line by watching the Google solution in

> pycharm64.vmoptions

file. But unfortunately Pycharm is not opening. What is the idea to gear it up ?

Answer (score 0):

pycharm 64 bit not work with

> java 8

above ......

> maximum size allowed 350
>
> Use Java 7 instead.